# Optimize Union All Mysql

Tags: mysql

I am working a big script which has a big database and for every page i should perform an union all query:

```
    (SELECT q.*
     FROM
         (SELECT q.*
          FROM iz q
          WHERE id <> 5
              AND langage = > 'en'
          ORDER BY nshares DESC LIMIT 50) q
     ORDER BY rand() LIMIT 3) >
UNION
    (SELECT q.*
     FROM
         (SELECT q.*
          FROM iz q
          WHERE id <> 5
              AND langage > = 'en'
          ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 20) q
     ORDER BY rand() LIMIT 7)
UNION
    (SELECT q.*
     FROM
         (SELECT q.*
          FROM iz q
          WHERE id <> 5
              AND langage = > 'en'
          ORDER BY rand() LIMIT 20) q
     ORDER BY rand() LIMIT 3)
ORDER BY > rand() LIMIT 8
```

This query take too much and when there is a load on the server it put a lot of load on cpu so i am thinking if i can find a way to optimize it. I have tried to decrease the limit on some queries without any result i have also tried to use union all instead of union but nothing seems to work.
Is there anyone who can help ?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

How about some caching? At least the first two inner queries which order by nshares and id desc could be cached into a temp table. Update them with a cronjob every minute.

Comment: It is the only available solution to my case ?

Comment: It is a quick solution with a lot of performance gain I could think of. Not sure if there are other ways. Maybe you can limit the multiple rand() calls to one call. I am not sure how to do that yet.